# Scale svg path with Javascript

Tags: jquery, html, svg

I have this **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y0f1vk1r/2/)**.

When I click onto the path, I want to zoom it. But after the zoom, the clicked path lost his current position.

Here my jQuery code:

```
var svg = $("#svg-container");

svg.load("svg/fondcarte-collec_actuelle.svg", function(data) {
  svg.children().find("path").click(function(e) {
    $("#Layer_1 path").removeAttr("style");
    var x =  e.pageX - svg.width() - $(this).offset().left - this.getBoundingClientRect().width + svg.find("svg").offset().left + 250;
    var y = e.pageY - svg.height() - $(this).offset().top - this.getBoundingClientRect().height + svg.find("svg").offset().top + 250;
    console.log(this.x, this.y)
    $(this).css("transform", "translate(" + x + "px, " + y + "px) scale(1.3)");
    $(this).css("fill", "green");
  })
})
```

- **How can I zoom it without losing the current position?**
- **Could anyone give a website with svg tutorial and manipulation?**

I want a result like the picture below:
[image]

How can it be done?

**Note:** I asked it without plugin because I want to understand this zoom concept.

Comment: Just set `transform-origin: 50% 50%;` and remove all the complication with the `translate` and you should get something very close to what you are looking for. Note that you'll probably also need to manipulate the order of the elements so that the element you want to see "over" the others is the last one.

Comment: Wow, it works thank you.
Can you set this comment as anwser and I will mark it as resolve?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MortenMuulder's solution is nearly there.  It is not quite the entire solution however.

There is currently a problem with the way percentage values in `transform:orgin` work when applied to SVG elements. Chrome and Firefox aren't consistent with one another.  Technically Firefox is the one that follows the current spec. You can read more about that in other S.O questions on the topic.

To work around this, you'll need to calculate the centre of the region yourself.  You can do that by calling `getBBox()` on the element. That returns the elements position, width, and height.

```
var bbox = this.getBBox();
var centreX = bbox.x + bbox.width/2;
var centreY = bbox.y + bbox.height/2;
```

The other thing you'll need to do, is to move the current region in front of all the others.  To do that, you need to move it so that it is last element.  We can do that with:

```
this.parentElement.appendChild(this);
```

We get the parent element and append the current element to the end of it's children.  That has the effect of moving it.

So the final click handler will look something like this:

```
svg.children().find("path").click(function(e) {
  $("#Layer_1 path").removeAttr("style");
  $this = $(this);
  var bbox = this.getBBox();
  var centreX = bbox.x + bbox.width/2;
  var centreY = bbox.y + bbox.height/2;
  $this.css("transform-origin", centreX + 'px ' + centreY + 'px');
  $this.css("transform", "scale(2)");
  $this.css("stroke", "white");
  $this.css("fill", "green");
  this.parentElement.appendChild(this);
})
```

[Demo fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/y0f1vk1r/4/)

**Update 2020**

The issue with Firefox and Chrome behaving differently has been resolved now.  The CSS group has added a new CSS property, `transform-box`, which allows you to specify how percentage `transform-origin` are calculated.

Chrome's old (incorrect) behaviour of calculating percentages based on the element bounding box can be reproduced in all browsers now by setting `transform-box` to `fill-box`.  This simplifies the code a bit.

```
$this.css("transform-origin", "50% 50%");
$this.css("transform-box", "fill-box");
$this.css("transform", "scale(2)");
```

[New demo fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/t1we7jn8/)

Answer (score 4):

https://jsfiddle.net/mortenmoulder/y0f1vk1r/3/

```
$(this).css("transform-origin", "50% 50%");
$(this).css("transform", "scale(2)");
$(this).css("stroke", "white");
```

Removing the original transform works fine, as long as you remember to set the `transform-origin` to `50% 50%`. I also scaled up the element and added some stroke. Since we have some z-index issues, you could look into [<use>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/use), or simply changing the order of how they're "painted". The first element in the SVG will be drawn on top of the others.

Comment: The last element, actually.

Comment: On Firefox, it's shifted. Why does firefox behave like this?

Comment: Firefox is behaving correctly. It is Chrome that is technically incorrect. Percentage values for `transform-origin` on SVG elements work differently that they do on HTML elements.

Comment: So could you show me how can I have the same render on chrome and firefox?

Comment: @RadonirinaMaminiaina Use another browser. Firefox and SVGs don't go hand in hand.

Comment: @MortenMoulder, it's a difficult because, the client may want to use firefox as well as chrome

Comment: @RadonirinaMaminiaina I have no clue then.